# How to Edit custom UITableViewCell's Frame size?

Tags: iphone

I am using custom UITableViewCell class to make table view cell. I am changing row height dynamically:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60;
}
```

Its working for row height perfectly.

But this only changing the row height, not the Cell's Frame height. The Cell frame height is still 44 (default). So how can I make it effective for both row height as well as cell frame?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Patidar:   How do you know that **Cell frame height is 44 not 60** ?

Comment: I was debugging the application by using breakpoints. In tableViewCell class I used self.frame.size.height to get the cell height.

Answer (score 0):

while creating the cell in cellforrow

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

 if (cell == nil) 
 {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,90,90) reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
 }
return cell;
```

}

note this line

```
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,90,90) reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
```

CGRectMake(0,0,90,90) change this as u needed

Comment: Hi friends, Thanks for your reply. But this is not enough for my case. These seems like to pass static cell frame in init method. I want an dynamic cell height, which should be same as row height. Note: Row height will not be static in my case. I used 60 just for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just write one line in cellForRowIndexAtPath: data source method.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,60);

}
```